# Asp.net core mvc 2.0 - bootstrap.css not being publised

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Something has happened to my Asp.net core mvc 2.0  recently in that the 'bootstrap.css' is now no longer being published to the live site (it used to!) and works fine on the local site.

Here are the refs in the shared _Layout.cshtml..

```
<environment include="Development">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Here are the refs from the html source in my local site which are missing in the live site..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />52
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: What you using? Visual Studio? VSCode? How are you publishing? Via IDE, via Azure DevOps/Jenkins/similar?

Comment: VS 2017.  Publishing from VS2017 to a local folder and then ftp to web host